# Swift and Facebook SDK 4, Graph API

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

Trying to put Facebook integration into a trial app I'm working on and can't seem to find an efficient way to make a friends list with a small profile pic from fb beside them. everything works flawless but the lengthy wait times on the data fetch. Please help with anything that will speed up image fetch times. Currently it takes about 10 seconds to fetch.

```
func facebookProfilePicRequest(){
            let graphConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
            for result in self.facebookFriends {
                if let resultingId = result["id"] as? String{

                    let profilePicRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(resultingId)/picture?redirect=false", parameters: nil)
                    graphConnection.addRequest(profilePicRequest){
                        (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in


                        if(error != nil){
                            if error.code == 1009{
                                println("No Internet Connection, \(error.code))")
                            }
                        }else{
                            if let data: NSDictionary = result as? NSDictionary{
                                if let urlDictionary: NSDictionary = data["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                                    if let urlString: NSString = urlDictionary["url"] as? NSString{
                                        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString as String)!
                                        var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
                                        let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
                                        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                            if error == nil{
                                                self.facebookFriendsImages.append(data)
                                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            graphConnection.start()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fetching all the images by yourself, you could use Facebook provided `FBSDKProfilePictureView`. You only have to set the user profile ID, and it would load the picture for you.

This should improve things as it doesn't have to wait for all the images to be loaded before showing them, and it also load them asynchronously as you scroll the tableview.

Comment: I'm using this for my main app view, i don't know why i didnt think of this. Thanks